# How to use multiple words in Quick filter box in Sitecore powershell Show-Listview

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am new for Sitecore Powershell, In the script I am using Show-Listview to display the result and it is providing option to Filter the result data. Powershell doc stating we can use multiple words in Filter box but If I use multiple words (for diff column values) it's not displaying any result.

Can you suggest how to use multiple words in the quick filter box in Show-listview

[image]

Comment: I think this may be an issue. I've reported it here https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/801.

Comment: I've since implemented this feature. You can update to the latest version of the module to start using it.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple keyword search is actually a relatively new feature to SPE and is only available in [SPE version 4.4](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases/tag/4.4) or later. Check to ensure that that you are using SPE 4.4 or later and then you will be able to use keyword search in the following ways (per the [issue comments](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/801) by the developer, @AdamNajmanowicz):

#### All words on item

All keywords searched for must be present on the item, though they can be in separate fields.

e.g. Searching for `hello world` will search for items that have the word `hello` in at least one field and the word `world` in at least one field.

#### Literal phrase on item

The quoted phrase searched for must be found as-is on one of the item's fields

e.g. Searching for `"hello world"` will search for items that have the literal phrase `hello world` in at least one field.

#### Getting the latest SPE

If you are not using the SPE 4.4 or later, you can find the download for the latest SPE release, [here](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases).